# Should I merge a preprint with the peer-reviewed version of this article on Google Scholar if the preprint has already been cited?

Tags: google-scholar, preprint

I have uploaded a preprint to PsyArXiv in 2021. The preprint is now published in a peer-reviewed journal. Normally, I merge the two so that only my published articles show up. However, this time my preprint was cited, and I'm not sure if I lose the citation count after merging.

Does anyone happen to have experience with a similar situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Merging two versions of an article will combine their citation counts, so there is no harm in doing so. More specifically, it will likely display the combined citation count with an asterisk, which indicates that this is the sum from two forms of the article.

It is also commonly the case that google scholar will eventually realize itself that the two are versions of the same article and automatically merge them, again combining the citations (without an asterisk in this case). This can often take many months after both are indexed.

Comment: @ Rococo The preprint version already was in my scholar. I added a published one manually but when I click on it, it shows the same in preprint and goes through that website. Shall I wait scholar to do it itself.